# What is a class library?

Tags: c#, libraries, definition

I'm working on a lawsuit and I need a definition of a 'class library' that I can reference. Every book and all the documentation I can find seems to assume the reader already knows what a library is. Even the wikipedia entry on 'Library (computing)' is low on references. And the references it does have are from the 80s or earlier.

So, in the context of C#, what is a class library? (with references)

I have been getting a decent number of definitions from 'Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software' but it also assumes the reader knows what a library is.

Comment: I'm not sure an answer here is going to stand up to legal scrutiny.

Comment: I'm not looking for an answer, I'm looking for someone to hopefully knows of a reference that has a definition.

Comment: You could try [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: From a programmer perspective, "class library" is typically associated with a package-and-release process by one software provider (closed-source or open source) so that it can be used by other programmers. Perhaps the [articles on Object Mentor](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/granularity.pdf) may contain phrases to help you find *references that match whatever you have in your mind*.

Comment: A class library is a [library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) containing [classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)).

Comment: Do you have to use the term “class library”? Couldn't you instead use more technical terms like “[assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3677y81)”?

Answer (score 3):

The term "class library" is an ambiguous assertion that can vary wildly by language, runtime, and convention. Even if we were to limit the discussion only to C#, it would be difficult to find a useful definition as to what is and is not a class library.

The particular features of C# actually make this more complicated, as a "class library" might be a NuGet package, an assembly intended to be used in another program, a collection of *.cs files meant to provide parent or special case classes, or some combination of the same.  Even mere confusing, any of the above could contain more than one "class library", or code that is not part of any "class library".

Since you mentioned a lawsuit, presumably you have some disagreement that hinges on what is and is not a "class library", and the contract in question either did not specify a precise definition or included one that either you or the other party wants to discard.  If such is the case, you likely cannot get out of arguing the definition in court, even if you found a clear and unambiguous definition from the. national programmer's union.

Of course if the definition of "class library" is not material to your lawsuit, just go with an ambiguous definition.  (A group of one or more classes, which may be presented in any form and may or may not be all contained in the same namespace or written in the same language.

Answer (score 2):

From [University of Washington School of Law website](http://www.law.washington.edu/lta/swp/law/derivative.html):

> The central programming abstractions provided by object-oriented languages are those of *objects* and *classes*. Objects represent real, functioning program entities that contain data and can respond to certain messages. Classes are a means of defining and organizing a world of objects. A class defines the data and behaviors of a group of objects. For example, a programmer may wish to build a student database application for a university. In doing so, she may create a class called `Student` that defines the relevant characteristics of a student. These characteristics may include data such as name, student ID number, and GPA. They may also contain behaviors that students can perform. For instance, a student might know how to take exams, complain, and ask questions. Finally, classes may relate to each other by means of *inheritance*. In our example, our programmer might create a *subclass* of `Student` called `GradStudent` that specializes and/or extends the behaviors of `Student` in some manner. For instance, a `GradStudent` may prefer to complain about his or her advisor, whereas a generic `Student` may typically prefer to complain about grades. Inheritance allows the programmer to easily reuse much of the functionality of existing classes, by defining a subclass that overrides certain default behaviors of its *superclass*. (Some object-oriented languages, C++ for example, use the term base class for superclass and derived class for subclass. For obvious reasons, we shall avoid the use of those terms here.)

In the [technology primer](http://www.law.washington.edu/lta/swp/Tech/techprimer.html) (also from University of Washington School of Law), the page also goes into some detail about Software Decomposition. This will give you an easy to understand explanation of what a class is without requiring the legal definition.

Comment: I find this definition highly dubious: The central abstraction provided by an object-oriented language is messaging, not necessarily objects and certainly not classes. There are plenty of OO languages that don't have classes (Self, for example) and some don't even have objects (Erlang, for example – it does have objects, but it calls them *processes* and ECMAScript – it has a concept called "object" but that's just a hash table, objects are actually built using closures). Plus, in languages like Java and C#, classes don't define objects, they define ADT instances. Interfaces define objects.